# AngularJS : service not returning value

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm trying to write an Angular service and it seems like there is something missing. My problem is its not returning any value to my Angular controller

`getPrepTimes()` method is not returning the http data

But when I check the network (via Chrome dev tools) it will correctly call the external api and return a json object as a response

```
#my service
'use strict';
angular.module('recipeapp')
  .service('prepTimeService',['$http', function($http){
      this.prepTime = getPrepTimes();

      function getPrepTimes(){
          $http({
            url: '/prep_times/index.json',
            method: 'GET'
          })
          .success(function (data, status, header, config){
            return data;
          });
      };
  }
  ]);




#controller
'use strict';

angular.module('recipeapp')
  .controller('recipeCtrl', ['$scope', 'prepTimeService', function($scope, prepTimeService){
     $scope.prep_time = prepTimeService.prepTime;
  }]);
```

When I checked the method `getPrepTimes()` with returning a string it works. What could be missing here?

Comment: It shouldn't work,...you can't `return` from an AJAX call, you have to use a callback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple things are wrong with the above. You assign `this.prepTime` to `getPrepTimes()`. The `()` there will invoke `getPrepTimes` immediately, and not when you actually call it! You also need to utilize callbacks to get your data back and use it:

```
angular.module('recipeapp').service('prepTimeService',['$http', function($http){
    this.prepTime = getPrepTimes;

    function getPrepTimes(callback) {
        $http({
            url: '/prep_times/index.json',
            method: 'GET'
        }).success(function (data, status, header, config){
            callback(data);
        });
    };
}]);
```

And now use it like so:

```
 prepTimeService.prepTime(function(data) {
     $scope.prep_time = data;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Calls to the `$http` service are async, which means you need to return a promise (and not a value):

```
this.prepTime = function() {
    return $http({
      url: '/prep_times/index.json',
      method: 'GET'
    });          
};
```

And on the controller:

```
angular.module('recipeapp')
  .controller('recipeCtrl', ['$scope', 'prepTimeService', function($scope, prepTimeService){
    $scope.prep_time = prepTimeService.prepTime()
      .success(function (data, status, header, config){
        $scope.someVar = data;
      });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap answer with promise:

```
var self = this;

var deferred = $q.defer();

self.getPrepTimes = function() {
        $http({
            url: '/prep_times/index.json',
            method: 'GET'
        })
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                    if (data.error === undefined) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    } else {
                        if (data.error !== undefined) {

                        } else {
                            deferred.reject(data);
                        }
                    }

                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

In controller call it:

```
 prepTimeService.getPrepTimes().then(function(result) {
     $scope.prep_time = result;
    },
    function(error) { 
     // show alert           
   });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,  I'm pretty new to angular and for me `promise` are still bit confusing.. so trying to keep away from them for the moment :)

Comment: @sameera207 for the future homework :) promises give you ability to pass to controller also errors. Consider that http failed and you want to show up some popup, in this case you *reject* the answer and in controller enter to `function(error)`